# Remove everything after first character in list of names

Tags: regex, perl, sed, awk, cut

I have a list of names I  want to combine two list first name and last name.  I want to drop everything after the second character in the First name.  For example:
First Name

```
Adam
Adam
Amanda M
Amber
Ami
Amy
Amy
Amy
Amy
```

Output

```
A
A
A
A
A
A
A
A
A
```

Answer (score 2):

are you looking for this?

```
sed 's/^\(.\).*/\1/' file
```

or simply:

```
grep -o '^.' file
```

Answer (score 2):

Using awk:

```
awk -F '\0' '{print $1}' file
```

OR pure BASH:

```
while read l; do
   echo ${l:0:1}
done < file
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `cut`:

```
$ echo "Adam
Adam
Amanda M
Amber
Ami
Amy
Amy
Amy
Amy" | cut -c 1
A
A
A
A
A
A
A
A
A
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/\B.*//' file
```